# xml xsd processing library for freebsd

Tags: c, xml, dom, xsd, freebsd

I need to process xml and xsd docs into a 'C' program I am writing on freebsd. 
Does anyone know if any libraries available (must be some like XML DOM) so that I do not need to read it like text and do all stupid things?

For example: I want to do operations like, adding a particular node at a designated place in the xml node tree and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should look at [libxml2](http://www.libxml.org/). It has a DOM interface and most other things you might want to do at a node manipulation level. I'm not sure from your question if you need XSD validation or not. There is an incomplete [xsd validation plugin](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlschemas.html#xmlSchemaSAXPlug) but I've not used it so I can't comment further on that.

Comment: yes, thats what I found out. libxml2 is the winner! Thanks anyways.